# Saving to a file in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have to save unique passwords and usernames to a file, but my code duplicate the first two entries, then start working properly from there. here's my code. What am I missing? I using Mac with MAMP. I'm testing the code using `curl` with this command `curl -d login=tenten -d passwd=peter -d submit=OK 'http://localhost:8080/php/create.php'`

```
function user_exist($user_array, $user_name)
{
    foreach ($user_array as $user) {
        if ($user['login'] === $user_name)
            return (TRUE);
}
    return (FALSE);
}

if ($_POST['submit'] === 'OK')
{
    if ($_POST['passwd'] != "" && $_POST['login'] != "")
    {
        create_file('../private');
        if (file_exists('../private/passwd'))
        {
            $hash_passwd = hash('whirlpool', $_POST['passwd']);
            $passwds = unserialize(file_get_contents('../private/passwd'));
            if (!user_exist($passwds, $_POST['login']))
            {
                $passwds[] = array('login' => $_POST['login'], 'passwd' => $hash_passwd);
            $serialize = serialize($passwds);
                file_put_contents('../private/passwd', $serialize);
                echo "OK\n";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $hash_passwd = hash('whirlpool', $_POST['passwd']);
            $user_cred = array('login' => $_POST['login'], 'passwd' => $hash_passwd);
            $serialize = serialize($user_cred);
            file_put_contents('../private/passwd', $serialize);
            echo "OK\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR\n";
}
```

Comment: What's `create_file`?

Comment: I do see a problem.  Upon first creation, you serialise and save a one dimensional array.  Then later you have an array of arrays.

Comment: Please keep in mind that POST values should ALWAYS be sanitized

Comment: @Progrock thanks, that was the problem.